# How do mallard mother ducks tell their ducklings from others?

Tags: birds, bird-behaviour, ducks

Right now the irrigation ditches and ponds have lots and lots of mallard ducklings, sometimes multiple families to a single pond. The way to tell is that there will be too many ducklings for one family in a pond, and they will sort of be grouped up.

[image]

I have read that mother ducks will not tolerate strange ducklings around their own, but **how do they tell the difference between their own ducklings and unrelated ones?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most of the birds identify their young by calls. This is a survival trait in birds which allows them to locate their young when they are out of sight. Same applies for ducks as well. As far as I know, the imprinting mechanism ([can lead to some hilarious behaviour](https://www.dogonews.com/2014/5/15/imprinting-causes-baby-ducklings-to-believe-that-a-man-is-their-mother)) that works for the ducklings doesn't have a big effect on the parent to child relationship. In animals, the smell and calls play a major role in parents recognising their offsprings.

Comment: Smell plays a major role for mammals, but most birds don't have sense of smell at all, so they need to rely on sight and hearing.